# How to make a button insert data into my database?

Tags: python, sqlite, pyqt5

I'm doing a little python product registration program and the database just doesn't open

I tried to open with sqlite3 library and by suggestion tried with QSqlDatabase, but nothing works. What could this error be? How to solve and connect?

i changed the database connection

```
path = r'C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\Sistema NaruHodo\Banco de Dados'
conn = sqlite3.connect(path+r'\produtos.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()
```

Erro:

```
C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\pythonw.exe "C:/Users/Daniel/Desktop/Sistema NaruHodo/cadastroprodutos.py"

Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)
```

Here is the def I'm using to try to get the field data and insert it into the database.

```
    def addProduto(self, produtotext, estoquetext, precocustotext, precovendatext, fornecedorcomboBox):
        path = r'C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\Sistema NaruHodo\Banco de Dados'
        conn = sqlite3.connect(path+r'\produtos.db')
        produto = str(self.produtotext.text())
        estoque = float(self.estoquetext.text())
        precocusto = float(self.precocustotext.text())
        precovenda = float(self.precovendatext.text())
        fornecedor = str(self.fornecedorcomboBox.currentText())
        conn.execute(f"""INSERT INTO produ VALUES (null, {produto}, {estoque}, {precocusto}, {precovenda}, {fornecedor})""")
        conn.commit()
```

Comment: Have you been successful connecting the button to a function that does something simple like print something?

Comment: Yes and it worked!

Comment: mmmm You can have several accounts in SO but the idea is not to abuse it, in your case it seems that you want to have 2 questions with the same content in both accounts.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58406034/problems-opening-database-using-qsqldatabase-in-pycharm, So you should keep the questions as they are or delete one of them.

Comment: It's supposed to be `addDatabase()` not `database()`.

Comment: You are correctely thank you

Comment: But i have a new erro:
C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\pythonw.exe "C:/Users/Daniel/Desktop/Sistema NaruHodo/cadastroprodutos.py"

Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)

Comment: Looks like you are trying to open two simultaneous connections to the database. Only use 1 connection. And again, you really should use`QSqlDatabase` like I recommended instead of the `sqlite3` standard library.

Comment: 237/5000
I solved the problem, with QSqlDatabase it did not accept and gave drivers error, so I went back to sqlite3. But it was still crashing even connected, so I found that the problem was really in the function that I didn't convert to string

Comment: @DanielOliveira In SO you should not add SOLVED in the title or add the answer in the question, for this you can publish an answer explaining your solution in detail.

Comment: Ok my friend...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, with QSqlDatabase it did not accept and gave drivers error, so I went back to sqlite3. But it was still crashing even connected, so I found that the problem was really in the function that I didn't convert to string

```
    def addProduto(self):
        self.banco = sqlite3.connect('Vendas.db')
        self.cursor = banco.cursor()
        Nome = self.produtotext.text()
        Quant = self.estoquetext.text()
        Valor = self.precocustotext.text()
        Preco = self.precovendatext.text()
        Forn = self.fornecedorcomboBox.currentText()
        if Nome != '' or Quant != '' or Valor != '' or Preco != '' or Forn != '':
            self.banco.execute(f"""INSERT INTO Produtos VALUES ('{Nome}',{Quant}, {Valor}, {Preco}, '{Forn}')""")
            self.banco.commit()
            self.LoadDatabase()
            self.limparcampos()
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to display the database in a table. I recommend using a [`QSqlDatabase`](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtSql/QSqlDatabase.html) to create a connection to the database (it does support an SQLite driver). Using this instead of `sqlite3` allows for better integration with the PyQt5 framework. Specifically, it can be easily hooked up with a [`QSqlTableModel`](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtSql/QSqlTableModel.html) and then displayed with a [`QTableView`](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtWidgets/QTableView.html). For this approach, I suggest you familiarise yourself with [model/view programming](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html). It may seem more involved and complex than the `QTableWidget` you are currently using, but it's well worth it for the easy database integration it offers.

Excuse some of the doc links being for PySide2; the PyQt5 docs aren't exactly complete unfortunately.

Comment: I would do that later, but the table is not showing anything yet, I haven't connected it to the database yet I was just trying to make the button save the data to the database without showing it to the table but unfortunately the program crashes when I click on the button. I thought my role could be wrong. But thanks for the advice, I will use this when showing in the tables.

Comment: Do you think working with PySide2 is more beneficial?

Comment: I realise I didn't answer your immediate problem but I felt you were going down the wrong path with how you approached your program and saw it as detrimental to continue. Regarding PySide2, I mainly prefer it because of the license but it's also a good idea to take a look at [which bindings are missing](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Python_Missing_Bindings) compared to PyQt5. Regardless, the PySide2 docs are more or less usable for PyQt5 since both libraries are pretty faithful to the C++ version on which they are based. I even use the C++ docs sometimes because it's more convenient.

Comment: I found that the problem is with the database that does not connect, i go edit the question